# MySQL, group by two different columns

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

My table looks like:

```
╔═════╦═════════════════════╦═════════════════════╦═════════════╗
║ id  ║        begin        ║         end         ║ employeesId ║
╠═════╬═════════════════════╬═════════════════════╬═════════════╣
║   4 ║ 2015-11-11 00:00:00 ║ 2015-11-11 09:00:00 ║           8 ║
║  80 ║ 2015-11-11 09:00:00 ║ 2015-11-11 12:00:00 ║           8 ║
║  49 ║ 2015-11-11 00:00:00 ║ 2015-11-11 08:00:00 ║          61 ║
║  32 ║ 2015-11-11 08:00:00 ║ 2015-11-12 06:00:00 ║          61 ║
║  42 ║ 2015-11-12 07:00:00 ║ 2015-11-12 13:00:00 ║          61 ║
║  17 ║ 2015-11-11 00:00:00 ║ 2015-11-11 08:00:00 ║          22 ║
║  42 ║ 2015-11-11 09:00:00 ║ 2015-11-11 12:00:00 ║          22 ║
╚═════╩═════════════════════╩═════════════════════╩═════════════╝
```

I want to merge rows where columns `employeesId` are equal, and `begin` time of one row is equal to `end` time of another row. Like this:

```
╔═════════════════════╦═════════════════════╦═════════════╗
║        begin        ║         end         ║ employeesId ║
╠═════════════════════╬═════════════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 2015-11-11 00:00:00 ║ 2015-11-11 12:00:00 ║           8 ║
║ 2015-11-11 00:00:00 ║ 2015-11-12 06:00:00 ║          61 ║
║ 2015-11-12 07:00:00 ║ 2015-11-12 13:00:00 ║          61 ║
║ 2015-11-11 00:00:00 ║ 2015-11-11 08:00:00 ║          22 ║
║ 2015-11-11 09:00:00 ║ 2015-11-11 12:00:00 ║          22 ║
╚═════════════════════╩═════════════════════╩═════════════╝
```

edit:

> I need to merge continuous datetimes, in this example you can see that end time '2015-11-11 12:00:00' for employeesId = 8 replaced end time '2015-11-11 09:00:00' in first row because begin of the second row is equal to end of the first row.

Comment: *I want to* what's holding you back?

Comment: Sorry, I need to, but I'm didn't manage to do it so that's why I'm asking for help here. :)

Comment: Please clarify what you have tried that didn't work or what you otherwise have problems with

Comment: I have completely no idea how to do it. I need it quickly but I'm not so qood at mysql and I couldn't find answer anywhere on the Web.

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥıλɐɯ no, the end time should be 06:00:00 because date is  12, one day later, so the thing is I need to merge dates that continue each other..

Comment: Consider providing a more properly representative data set - preferably as a set of CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or and sqlfiddle) - AND a corresponding result.

Comment: Also, you have two '32's. This should not be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try join

```
SELECT a.`begin_date`, IF(b.`end_date` IS NOT NULL, b.`end_date`, a.`end_date`), a.`employer_id`
FROM `mytable` a
LEFT JOIN `mytable` b ON a.`employer_id` = b.`employer_id` AND a.`end_date` = b.`begin_date`
LEFT JOIN `mytable` c ON a.`employer_id` = c.`employer_id` AND a.`begin_date` = c.`end_date`
WHERE c.`id` IS NULL
```

But you should rebuild your schema.

Comment: Due to `begin` and `end` being keywords for SQL, you'd have to use back ticks around them

Comment: @SamSwift like that? ;)

Comment: Yep, perfection! Haha

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥıλɐɯ I have SQL interpreter in my head.

Comment: @stachu But I have SQL interpreter on computer and it returns all data

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥıλɐɯ maybe I have old version. Give me a moment, I update data and try again.

Comment: @stachu good you tried, even thus this question now is on hold.

Comment: This is what I needed. Thank You.

Comment: @Luka I am glad that I can help :) but two joins are not good :(

Comment: @stachu I will try to find some better solution but I need that quickly so it will work for now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MIN(),MAX()` if you want to get earlier and later times.

```
SELECT MIN(begin),MAX(end),employeesId
    FROM table_name
    GROUP BY employeesId
```

Hope this helps

Comment: @Strawberry what is wrong with this statement? I just try it for fun on mysql and returns the correct results?

Comment: This works for given example, but not working if you add row like: begin(2015-11-11 09:00:00), end(2015-11-11 12:00:00), employeersId(22)

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥıλɐɯ What if employee 61 pops back in on the 14th?

Comment: I got you guys. I was narrow thinking ;) good catch, but I must admit this was the best not working answer so far from others ;)